# Which threading model should be used to create a Feed Handler Or Adaptor

Tags: c++, asynchronous, winsock, feed, adaptor

Hi to all the experts out there :)

This is my first question here.

Problem Description :

I have to write a Market Data Feed Handler. This is going to be a Windows Service, will be using two Sockets.

Socket A : For communication between Subscribing applications and Feed Handler (Feed Handler will be accepting the connection request and the Item Request).

Socket B : For communication between Feed Handler and External Market Data provider, like Reuters/Bloomberg.

In both the cases Request/Response will be using the same port.

Note : The volume of Data coming from the external system is low (External system will only send the information which has been subscribed for, at this point of time).
However later on we may want to scale it, some providers throw all the data, and Feed Handler has to filter out locally, based on the subscription.

My questions :

1. What threading model i should use?
2. Which I/O strategy i should use?
3. Keeping in mind both the cases, should i create separate Request/Response thread?

EDIT 1: After reading few tutorials on Winsock, i'm planning to use Event Objects for asynchronous behavior.

The point of concern here is that, a single thread should listen for incoming client connections (Accept them) and also Connect to other server, in turn send/recv on two different ports.

Thread A 
    1) Listening for incoming connections. (Continuous)
    2) Receiving Subscribe/Unsubscribe request from connected clients. (Rarely) 
    3) Connect to the external server (Onetime only). 
    4) Forward the request coming from client to the external server. (Rarely)
    5) Receive data from external server. (Continuous)
    6) send this data back to the connected clients. (Continuous)

My question is can a single thread act as both Client and Server, using asynchronous I/O models?

Thanks in advance.
Deepak

Answer (score 0):

The easiest threading model seems to be single threaded synchronous. If you need to implement a filter for a provider,  implement that as a socket-in/socket-out separate process.